# Changing multiple images

Tags: javascript, image

I've been having problems recently with a piece of code that I have been working on. I am asked to create an array and cycle through the traffic lights with a button, this is what I have done:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<head>
<title> Traffic Lights </title>
</head>

<body>

<script>
whatPosition=1;
var images=["redlight.gif","redandamber.gif","greenlight.gif","amberlight.gif"];
function changeImage() {

if (whatPosition==0) {
document.getElementById("image").innerHTML=images[1];
whatPosition=1;

} 

else if (whatPosition==1){
document.getElementById("image").innerHTML=images[2]
whatPosition=2;
alert("I am an alert box!");
}
else if (whatPosition==2){
document.getElementById("image").innerHTML=images[3]
whatPosition=3;
}
else if (whatPosition==3){
document.getElementById("image").innerHTML=images[4]
whatPosition=4;
}
else if (whatPosition==4){
document.getElementById("image").innerHTML=images[0]
whatPosition=0;
```

Comment: images don't use `innerHTML` as they don't contain html, you probably meant to set the `src` attribute

Comment: Kenny, don't vandalize your question like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images don't have `innerHTML`, try this :

`document.getElementById("image").src = images[0];`

Comment: Thank you all, I've only recently started coding

Comment: No problem! Quick note: you might want to look into `switch` statements for situations like this.. [link](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `src` attribute.

```
<img src="" />
<!---^^^^^^---- You need to set this to make this work.
```

Replace all the:

```
document.getElementById("image").innerHTML=images[0];
```

With the **following format**:

```
document.getElementById("image").src = images[0]);
```

Comment: `setAttribute` for `src`? Just use `.src`

Comment: @Cerbrus Well, yeah. That's right too. `:)`

Comment: There is literally no reason to use `setAttribute`.

Comment: @Cerbrus Changed it.

Comment: @Cerbrus Updated it. Kindly check.

Comment: @Cerbrus Thanks. Just curious, why not?

Comment: Because you can access `.src`, which is faster, and shorter.

Comment: @Cerbrus Thanks... `:)`

Comment: Accessing the property directly is effectively faster ([JSPerf benchmark](http://jsperf.com/setattribute-vs-src2)).

Comment: @JeffNoel Sure thanks. `:)`