# Changing multiple images on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
position=0;
var tLight = ["red light.gif","red_and_amber_light.gif","green                  light.gif","amber light.gif"]

function changeImage() {
if (position==0) {
document.getElementById('myImage').innerHTML=tLight[1]
position=1;
}    
else if (position==1) {
document.getElementById('myImage').innerHTML=tLight[2]
position=2;
}    
else if (position==2) {
document.getElementById('myImage').innerHTML=tLight[3]
position=3;
}       
else if (position==3) {
document.getElementById('myImage').innerHTML=tLight[4]
position=4;
}       

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img id="myImage" src="red light.gif" width="100" height="180">
<button type="button"
onclick="changeImage()">click for da lite</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I cant seem to find the problem in this code and i don't know whether it is me being blind or.....? someone please help. I have looked at the chrome "Developer Tools" but this cant detect any issues.

Comment: Your image URL's have spaces ?

Comment: Also, setting the `innerHTML` of an image ,doesn't change the ***src*** attribute ?

Comment: no i have tried this in another document but it doesn't make any difference. Thanks though

Comment: Use: `setAttribute` function instead of `innerHTML`

Comment: oh ok thanks i will try the "src" attribute now.

Comment: THANK YOU this has saved me a whole lot of time with the src attribute and it works thanks man

Comment: Odd how this question and this [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34949547/problems-with-cycling-through-traffic-lights-using-javascript) look exactly alike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using "innerHTML" to "img" tag, you have to use "src" attribute to make it work:

```
document.getElementById('myImage').src = tLight[1]
```